# How to align subplots borders when one has label and not the other?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

In the below example, how can I have ax2 (bottom) taking the full space on the left?
By "taking full space" I mean extending the plot area to the left limit of the figure, ie. using also the whitespace left below the label title and ticks from ax1.

```py
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def example_plot(ax, fontsize=12):
    ax.plot([1, 2])
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=fontsize)

def example_plot_noY(ax, fontsize=12):
    ax.plot([1, 2])
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=fontsize)

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()

gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1])

example_plot(ax1)
example_plot_noY(ax2)

gs1.tight_layout(fig)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You may see  [ask] on what is missing in the question. Above all that is to explain what "taking the full space" means. Please explain clearly what you are trying to achieve. Also it would help to know what you have already tried - this gives insight on the actual problem.

Comment: You import matplotlib.gridspec but never actually use it. Did you have a look at [the gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) docs? At which point do you have a problem there?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: you're right, I mixed up my example codes. I corrected the question with gridspec.  
This is not my actual code but a reduction to the case that bothers me. I read gridspec's doc and use it more extensively in my actual code but I didn't find how to solve this particular issue.  
My project requires me to use the full available space and that is why I do not want to spoil this white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [GridSpec with Varying Cell Sizes](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-with-varying-cell-sizes).
You can add another column in the gridspec which takes up the space of the labels of the upper plot. If you afterwards call tight layout, you do not need to care about its width, it can be 0 size,

```
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[0, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,1])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1,0:])
# ...
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I take your answer because obviously it solves my question, thanks. However, I wanted to avoid that solution because I have a more complex grid so I will have to rewrite the rest of my code to fit that new column. I'm surprised that we can't handle the size of the plot area inside the subplot and "push" it to the limits of the subplot. Or are the labels "outside" of the subplot? I am not sure I visualise these "boxes" correctly.

Comment: That's correct. The black boxes are indeed the boxes (the axes), the labels are outside. By default any grid is hence along the lines of the boxes and aligns them nicely. In case this is not wanted some other solution needs to be found. The above is not the only one but probably the easiest, especially if `tight_layout` is to be used.